# splitting the numbers from a text box by 4 set of numbers each getting its sum and combine all last digits of each sum from each group

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<html>
<title> Test </title>

<body>
  <b>Paste Here (ctrl+v)</b>
  <br>
  <input id="boxx1" type="text" style="width:210px;" onKeyPress="boxx1KeyPress()" onKeyUp="boxx1KeyPress()">
  <br>
  <input type="button" Value="Clear Field" onClick="ClearField()">
  <br>
  <br>
  <b>Output 1</b> <input id="boxx2" type="text" style="width:370px;" readonly> <b>Comp 1</b><input id="comp1" type="text" style="width:180px;" readonly>
  <br>
  <br>
  <b>Output 2</b> <input id="boxx3" type="text" style="width:370px;" readonly> <b>Comp 2</b><input id="comp2" type="text" style="width:180px;" readonly>
</body>

<script>
  function boxx1KeyPress() {
    var boxx1 = document.getElementById("boxx1");
    var s = boxx1.value.replace(/[ ,]+/g, ",");
    var x = s;

    var lblValue = document.getElementById("boxx2");
    lblValue.value = "" + s;

    var points = lblValue.value.split(",");
    document.getElementById("boxx3").value = points.sort().join();


    var comp1 = document.getElementById("boxx2");
    var res = comp1.value.split(",", 4);
    document.getElementById("comp1").value = res;

    var comp2 = document.getElementById("boxx3");
    var res2 = comp2.value.split(",", 4);
    document.getElementById("comp2").value = res2;

  }

  function ClearField() {
    document.getElementById("boxx1").value = "";
    document.getElementById("boxx2").value = "";
    document.getElementById("boxx3").value = "";
    document.getElementById("comp1").value = "";
    document.getElementById("comp2").value = "";

  }
</script>

</html>
```

Hi I need your help guys.

I am lost and dont know what to do next. 
Thank you so much in advance for those who can help me out.

What I've done so far:

I am getting a set of numbers from a source that looks like this:

From Source: 22 21 65 1 23 54 65 13 11 32 99 65 43 44 55 3 4 5 88 99

Output 1 Result:  22,21,65,1,23,54,65,13,11,32,99,65,43,44,55,3,4,5,88,99

Comp1 Result: "this is what I need"

Output 2 Result: 1,11,13,21,22,23,3,32,4,43,44,5,54,55,65,65,65,88,99,99

Comp2 Result: "this is what I need"

This is a 20 set numbers with space as a separator as soon as this numbers are pasted in the "paste here" text box
a comma will replace the spaces and will show the result in the output textbox and In the second output textbox same thing will happen but in ascending order.

What I wanted to do:

From the numbers showing up on Output1 and Output2 I need those numbers group into 5 having 4 set of numbers each and find the sum of each group looks like this:

22,21,65,1  equal to 10**9**

23,54,65,13 equal to 15**5**

11,32,99,65 equal to 20**7**

43,44,55,3  equal to 14**5**

4,5,88,99   equal to 19**6**

now I need to get all last digits of each result and the numbers combined should show up in the Comp 1 text box it should look like this:

**95756**

same thing on the Comp 2 textbox the basis would be the Output 2 textbox.

Comment: So you're wanting to do this in JavaScript inside the browser?  Or is this for back end processing?  I'm trying to understand why you've tagged this as Java.

Comment: it shouldn't be tagged as Java.. should only be html.. sorry for the confusion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you

```html
<html>
<title> Test </title>

<body>
  <b>Paste Here (ctrl+v)</b>
  <br>
  <input id="boxx1" type="text" style="width:210px;">
  <br>
  <input type="button" Value="Add" onClick="go()">
  <input type="button" Value="Clear Field" onClick="ClearField()">
  <br>
  <br>
  <b>Output 1</b> <input id="boxx2" type="text" style="width:370px;" readonly> <b>Comp 1</b><input id="comp1" type="text" style="width:180px;" readonly>
  <br>
  <br>
  <b>Output 2</b> <input id="boxx3" type="text" style="width:370px;" readonly> <b>Comp 2</b><input id="comp2" type="text" style="width:180px;" readonly>
</body>
<script>
  function go() {
    var boxx1 = document.getElementById("boxx1");
    var s = boxx1.value.replace(/ /g, ",");

    var lblValue = document.getElementById("boxx2");
    lblValue.value = s;

    var points = s.split(",");

    var comp1 = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i += 4) {
      var sum = 0;
      for (var j = i; j < i + 4; j++) {
        sum += Number(points[j]);
      }
      comp1 += (sum % 10);
    }

    document.getElementById("comp1").value = comp1;

    var comp2 = '';
    document.getElementById("boxx3").value = points.sort().join();

    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i += 4) {
      var sum = 0;
      for (var j = i; j < i + 4; j++) {
        sum += Number(points[j]);
      }
      comp2 += (sum % 10);
    }

    document.getElementById("comp2").value = comp2;
  }

  function ClearField() {
    document.getElementById("boxx1").value = "";
    document.getElementById("boxx2").value = "";
    document.getElementById("boxx3").value = "";
    document.getElementById("comp1").value = "";
    document.getElementById("comp2").value = "";
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Can we eliminate the "add" button and just use the "keypress" function instead?

Comment: Your welcome. Yes, define `onchange` event for `boxx1`. Good luck @usernameon

Comment: Alright! yes I was able to figure it out just now.. Thank You so much!